# VB.Net Document Interface

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, document

Is there a way to create a VB.Net form that has a document editor in which the user can drag and drop items from a toolbar into the document.

Sort of like this https://corporate.morningstar.com/us/documents/MarketingOneSheets/AWO/ADV_AWO_OfficeReportStudio.pdf

The items that would be dragged in would be Live SSRS reports and we want the ability to the let the end user position them where they want on the document.

I tried finding document controls but I was unable to find one that would fit these requirements.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So you expect a company like [SAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAP_SE) who made close to 17 billion dollars in revenue last year to give out their tools for free?

Comment: I'm not looking to replicate their tools.  Our use for it is separate.  I just wanted to know if there was already toolkits or best practices out there to use that allow for this type of reporting functionality.